# 1 year old Avocado tree new leaves are shrinking after transplanting

Tags: transplanting, avocado

I transplanted my avocado tree outdoors, and after a month of transplanting it, I see a strange (non normal) development. It seems that the new **leaves are growing shrinked** (see the photo). Also those leaves have some red color on it (don't know if it is normal but it didn't happen before).
The  major change it has suffered is more exposure of sun, so I think maybe is that, but I really don't know. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

[image]

**EDIT** (more information):

Note that another thing that has changed is **temperature**. Now is more inestable, some days reached 10ºC at night.

Here is the pick of the leaf that is older than the previous one that is starting to suffering some issues too, maybe it can gives more detailed hints on what is happening.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Good news and not so good news. First, avocado tends to grow in spurts or flushes, rapidly producing new leaves in a cluster at the growing tips after a period of quiet where it does not appear to be moving at all. The sudden flush of growth often results in the new leaves lacking temporarily some nutrients which can affect the pigments which control the apparent colour of the new growth. Some redness is normal, and it goes away as the leaf grows to full size and usual operations.

Here is a pic of one of mine which has recently done the same thing in steadily cloudy or interior conditions:

[image: Avocado new growth]

The change in light levels probably has nothing to do with the redness.

Now for other stuff - your leaves look quite dog-eared and crinkly with some dead tissue patches which is not so normal. In addition there is that green shoot on the left side which appears covered in unfocused lumps and bumps which should be examined more closely. If you have a magnifying glass try to get more detail on what they are and if they move around.

Comment: Thanks for your response! your avocado looks really nice! I updated my post with the image of the blurred leaf behind, hope this can gives more information to save the avocado.